# Create an array of assemblies references

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have a method in C# that needs an array of assembly references `, params Assembly[] referenceAssemblies)`. How do I create an array of assembly references? I know that I need the assembly objects, but how do I create (or reference?) them. An example would be most helpful. Let's say that I am creating an array with references to `System` and `System.Web`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, this creates an array of `mscorlib` (containing most of the `System` namespace) and `System.Web`.

```
var myAssemblies = new[] {
    typeof(System.String).Assembly,
    typeof(System.Web.HttpApplication).Assembly
};
```

If, by `System`, you really mean `System.dll`, you can use `typeof(System.Uri)`, which is located in System.dll rather than mscorlib.dll.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is a `params` parameter, you don't need an array, you can just concatenate the assemblies. You can load assemblies in multiple, like [`Assembly.LoadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8(v=vs.110).aspx), which loads an assembly from a file location.

Some ideas for calling your method:

```
YourMethod
( yourOtherParameters
, Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\someAssembly.dll") /* assembly from a file */
, typeof(Label).Assembly /* get an assembly from a type */
);
```